# Internal working of Netlfix Zuul with Netflix Eureka

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

How does Netflix Zuul Exactly work along with Eureka for routing & service discovery? From my understanding, a service instance registers/deregisters itself with Eureka with its IP and port. When a request arrives at Zuul (which is the gateway for end user requests), it checks with its filters if the request has to be routed (pre/post/route filters). If the filter for a particular request is present, does it send a request to Eureka asking it for a list of all IP Addresses and Ports for a service instance which serves that filter?

If that is how it works, what kind of requests reach Zuul ? If my filter name is “example”, would it be `HTTP GET ipAddr:port/example ?` (IP add:port is that of the Zuul instance)

I haven’t been able to find any article which describes the exact flow of messages between the 2 services in terms of the kind of messages to be passed. It would be great if someone could share some resources as well for me to get a better understanding.